# can't able to connect flask and reactjs for the chat application which uses socketio

Tags: reactjs, flask

i have written a code in flask python for a chat application. i had used the Socket IO library for establish the connection between the client and server.. the server side code written in python flask and client side code written in React .  now its not able to connect together..

**python flask code for Server side :**

```py
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from  flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config ['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'
socketio = Socket IO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
  print('Received message: ' + message)
  emit('message', message, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  socketio.run(app)
```

**Reactjs code for client side:**

```jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000");

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (message.trim() !== "") {
      socket.emit("message", message);
      setMessage("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="message-container">
        {messages.Map((message, index) => (
          <div key={index}>{message}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Type your message..."
        />
        `<button type="submit">Send</button>`
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

is it able to connect together

for socketio client and server connection is possble through reactjs and flask python

Comment: Please post the error message you are seeing, which will help people understand the problem. This may not be related, but I think `Socket IO(app)` should probably be `SocketIO(app)`, and `messages.Map` should be `messages.map`

Comment: the flask applicataion is not executing .. this what showing in the URL "" The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again"""

Comment: Your flask application is working *"The requested URL was not found on the server"* this message is generated from flask server it is saying that you've not implemented url for "/". Since you're using socket so you don't have to create one just have to make small changes in your react provide flask root url and listen for message event.

Comment: And one more thing since you're deling with diffrent origins you've to implement [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) in flask for debugging check browser network tab you'll get server response with error.